# Regress residuals in second regression

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, modeling, residuals, instrumental-variables

I am wondering if anyone can point me to a paper/lecture notes on the rationale behind first running an OLS on a set of variables, and then in a second regression using the residuals of that regression as the dependent variable to regress on several new (but related) independent variables. To specify, this is not aiming for an IV/2SLS approach - there's no instrument here that's uncorrelated with the dependent variable in the "first stage." Instead, it aims to kind of set a standard across the sample set with the first result, and then attribute the differences from the market-wide (ie the residuals) on the 2nd set of variables.

First off, wouldn't this approach by definition limit the first regression to one independent variable for a regular OLS? Otherwise the dependent variable in the 2nd would be an nx2 matrix...

Overall, is there any purpose to such a process? I believe I have seen it done before, but my searches have come up mostly fruitless. Closest conversation I've found is this Stata thread: `http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2008-03/msg00264.html`

Comment: are you talking about something along these lines? "In analysing multivariable datasets it is common that in looking at the effect of some variable ($x_1$) on a dependent variable of interest ($y$), the effects of  a third continuous variable ($x_2$) are to be controlled for, for instance because its effects may confound those of $x_1$. In such circumstances it has become common to perform a regression of $y$ on $x_2$ and use the residuals from this regression in testing for the effects of $x_1$" [found it here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1046/j.1365-2656.2002.00618.x/full)

Comment: Yes, this should be helpful for background info - thank you.

Comment: Important to add here that the quote is only paraphrasing what other people say / do - the linked article explains why there is NO justification for this approach.

Answer (score 1):

@Robson wrote a comment that can serve as at least the start of an answer, especially with the note from Florian.  To quote Robson:

"In analysing multivariable datasets it is common that in looking at the effect of some variable (x1) on a dependent variable of interest (y), the effects of a third continuous variable (x2) are to be controlled for, for instance because its effects may confound those of x1. In such circumstances it has become common to perform a regression of y on x2 and use the residuals from this regression in testing for the effects of x1" found it [here](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1046/j.1365-2656.2002.00618.x) (Freckleton, 2002, On the misuse of residuals in ecology: regression of residuals vs. multiple regression, *J. Animal Ecology*

As the title and abstract make clear, and as Florian's comment points out, the TL DR of the article is "No, don't do this".

Answer (score -1):

What you're describing is called ['two-stage residual inclusion'](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/298884) or ['control function'](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/430684) approach. In a linear model, it gives exactly the same estimator as "traditional" two-stage least squares, as for instance derived by [Hansen, pp. 335-38](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/%7Ebhansen/econometrics/Econometrics2018Jan.pdf#page=346). But in both cases, you need a valid IV. So your idea of doing this without an instrument in the first stage won't work.

Comment: I've tried both methods often enough, obtaining exactly the same results from each, to know that they do work.  A reason for using the residual method is to allow for graphs that show a given X's relationship to Y after controlling for other predictors.  Sometimes the partial plot one obtains via the more standard, condensed method isn't quite what's desired.