# Which approach (probably similar to 2SLS) should I use in order to estimate effects of fitted and residual components? Thinking about CF but not sure

Tags: regression, panel-data, instrumental-variables

I assume that the growth of variable $Y$ depends on variable $X$, and that the variable $X$ depends on variable $Z$. I would like to estimate the effect of $X$ on the growth of $Y$, but to differentiate between the part of $X$ which is explained by $Z$ (fitted) and which is not (residual).

Currently, I am using a two stage approach, so that

$ X=a+bZ+u $

$ gY=c+d\hat{X}+f\hat{u}+hW+e $

where $W$ is some other explanatory variable (actually, a couple of them). Also, I am using county-level panel data, fixed effects models. I assume that $X$ is endogenous (in the second model), but I'm using the value of fitted and residual components at the beginning of the period after which the growth of $Y$ occurs, which I suppose should help with this issue.

I am not sure whether it is adequate to use such an approach. The most similar thing I was able to find is control function. In some papers about control functions it looks like it is necessary to include $W$ in the first equation, which I would rather not (because in this case I will lose a simple interpretation of residual and fitted components).

Do you have any suggestions about the possible approaches to use, fatal errors in my logic, or any similar empitical cases of such an estimation?

Comment: Not sure I get the question, but in such a linear setup CF and 2SLS are the same thing, and indeed in 2SLS controls like $W$ need to be included in both stages: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430684/2sls-and-control-functions-identity-of-estimator/430731#430731